# How to update localStorage variable and send to Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have a list of options. When you click one option I want to update the localStorage value with the data-id value of the clicked on link and then send the updated localStorage value through an Ajax call, but the problem is that localStorage value doesn't get actually updated unless the window refreshes. Is there a way to have the localStorage value updated without a full window refresh:

HTML

```
<div class="phonechoice" data-id="1">Option 1</div>
<div class="phonechoice" data-id="2">Option 2</div>
```

JQUERY

```
 //Update localStorage variable on click and send to ajax call

 $(document).on("click", '.phonechoice', function(){
    var mcid=$(this).data("id");
    localStorage.mastercaseid = mcid; // CHANGE LOCALSTORAGE VALUE
    // location.reload(); //WANT TO STOP THIS RELOAD 
    getresult(url_pullrecords); //execute ajax call
  });
```

AJAX CALL

```
         function getresult(url_pullrecords) {
             $.ajax
             ({
                 context: this,
                 crossDomain: true,
                 url: url_pullrecords,
                 type: "GET",
                 data:  {mcid:localStorage.mastercaseid}, 
                 //THIS VALUE ABOVE DOESN'T GET UPDATED UNLESS WINDOW IS REFRESHED
                 beforeSend: function(){
                 },
                 success: function(data){
                   $(".btnholder").before(data);
                 }                   
             });
            }
```

Comment: Really doesn't make sense since it would seem the only update is done in the click handler. How are you verifying all of this? And why are you not using proper localStorage API methods?

Comment: im printing out the variable after the localStorage has been updated and it's not showing the new value unless I refresh the window. the ajax call is still getting the older value.

Comment: why don't you just pass it into the function as another argument? Also if you uncomment `location.reload()` then page will reload before the ajax ever gets called

Comment: you're right. It was working and I was misinterpreting the results. The ajax results were appending themselves which is why I was confused and thought it was pulling the wrong data. In my head I thought they should be getting replaced completely and didn't notice the correct results were there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("click", '.phonechoice', function(e){
     var mcid=$(this).data("id");
     localStorage.setItem("mastercaseid", mcid); // CHANGE LOCALSTORAGE VALUE
      // location.reload(); //WANT TO STOP THIS RELOAD 
     e.stopPropagation();
     getresult(); //execute ajax call
 });
```